# Power and energy usage monitoring for Vechical Control Unit (VCU)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, computer-engineering, software, embedded-systems

I'm working on a project for an EV (electric vehicle) and I'm working on the VCU. I think the task that was given to me is to get all the data from a transformer or a DAQ (Data acquisition system) and send it to the VCU, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: please write out acronyms

Comment: @TigerGuy Hi, sorry about that, I wrote out the acronyms!

Comment: Figure out what data you need.  What is the purpose of "a transformer" and what values would you need to collect to ensure it is working? What is the purpose of the data acquisition and how often will you need to sample data?